# What would mammalian dinosaurs look like?

Tags: biology, xenobiology, dinosaurs, mammals

Here's a crazy idea: What if there were mammals that were designed similarly to dinosaurs? Similar proportions, similar accessories, maybe even similar size...

I was thinking of species to add to my story, and one that popped up was the idea of a fluffy cat-like creature designed to fit the shape of a T-Rex, with the giant legs, stubby arms, and huge head and tail. What physiological changes would be needed to convert a T-rex into a C-rex? How can this be applied to other species of dinosaur?

So far, the big issues that would need to be acknowledged are-

-How can tempurature regulation work for a fluffy mammal built to dinosaur scale? Can they even have fur at that point without their body temperature cooking them to death?

-What real-world environments can these creatures live in?

-How will the denser, heavier bone structure of mammals effect the mobility of these creatures?

-What about the gestation period for these birth-giving mammalian beasts?

All I really have for reference is the largest land mammal today, the African Bush Elephant, and extinct prehistoric species that theoretically reached the weight of the T-Rex, which I'm pretty sure is the limit for terrestrial mammals.

Extra personal constraints I've added are no changing the number of lungs, limbs or hearts these creatures have (unless that's actually a thing among mammals), the type of planet they're on (we're going with the same range of environments as modern earth) and any magical augmentations (I want this to be strictly physics-based)

Comment: Look at elephants and rhinos, they solve your "could they be fuzzy" question. Moreover, inosaurs had lots of adaptations to be able to become what they were, including hollow but sturdy bones, airsacks, special skulls with openings to reduce weight, etc, so unless your cat faces some serious anatomical changes, I doubt it can become a mammalian version of a t-rex

Comment: Worldbuilding.SE's policy is that you should restrict yourself to one question per question. Might I suggest splitting this up into a series of questions? It's an ungainly solution, but it does stave off the packs of rabid VTC-ers.

Answer (score 4):

The early protomammals were dinosaur-like. https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/laelaps/when-protomammals-ruled-earth/

The main difference is that dinosaurs were actually more advanced.

Then, there was the mega-fauna of the ice-age and just previous to the ice-age.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleistocene_megafauna

Giant ground sloths were particularly interesting looking. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megatherium

"Dinosaur-scale" is subjective, but blue whales are mammals that are larger than dinosaurs. As for fur, some people think that there were warm-blooded dinosaurs and many dinosaurs are now known to be heavily feathered. There are similar considerations for feathers and fur in terms of heat-retention.

Large creatures can be highly mobile. Consider the vast distances that elephant herds travel. Blue whales migrate across vast distances as well. The difference between charge speed and maintained travel should be considered.

To give birth, elephants must withstand a pregnancy lasting more than a year and a half. Whales have a similar gestation period. There was a very large mammal that you possibly already know of the Indricotherium. It was actually larger than the T-Rex.
https://www.reddit.com/r/Dinosaurs/comments/d54prs/trex_compared_to_one_of_the_largest_land_mammals/
https://www.kqed.org/quest/5351/the-largest-land-mammal-that-ever-lived

The main reason why we don't see mega-fauna animals of this size today is that it takes a massive amount of vegetation to feed large animals of this nature. Large mammalian carnivores were just slightly larger than polar bears today. Perhaps carnivore size is more limited for mammals than herbivore size for some reason.

Since this is world-building, one of the elements which has been linked to large size is oxygen concentration, though this is contested today. https://animals.howstuffworks.com/extinct-animals/why-were-prehistoric-animals-big.htm

There is also some physical size in mass that could be the theoretical limit for land animals. Lung capacity helps offset some of the key issues with physical size, with larger lungs being preferred. Cope's Law suggest that varieties of creatures tend to grow in size over time, as a result of evolutionary success. This might be true for some creatures more than others... perhaps "Law" was too ambitious of a term.

Animals tend to grow larger as they are less threatened and are less threatened as they grow larger. This gives a sort of evolutionary advantage to size, once a certain size is attained. Smaller creatures are more evasive, thrive more easily in sparse food conditions, and reproduce more rapidly. This is the competing evolutionary pressure. This gives you a set of conditions... less effective hunters, plentiful food, high oxygen, high land mass, and defensive herds (large animals often are found in herds). Humanity as the alpha predator of the planet constrains land animals to roughly elephant size. All larger animals have failed to evade humans or our precursors successfully, so Mammoths disappeared from the Earth. This means having ambush predators (like T-Rex) rather than persistence predators (like us) more ideal for large animal size. These animals cannot take on herds, unlike social hunters like ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

**How will the denser, heavier bone structure of mammals effect the mobility of these creatures?**

Organisms on Earth are constrained in their size by something called the square-cube law. Explained most simply with a cube:

```
Dimensions: 1m x 1m x 1m (l x w x h)
Surface area: 6m^2
Volume: 1m^3
```

Now multiply the size of the cube by 10:

```
Dimensions: 10m x 10m x 10m (each 10x larger)
Surface area: 600m^2 (100x larger)
Volume: 1000m^3 (1000x larger)
```

Since your C-rex is not going to be full of air, an increasing volume will greatly contribute to an increasing weight. The problem: volume grows *much faster* than surface area, and it's the cross-section of your surface area that is supporting all the weight above it. In short, you'll get more heavier faster than you'll get space to support it.

Options:

- **Denser bones.** They'll need stronger muscles though. And you'll need large cardiovascular and respiratory systems to provide enough oxygen.
- **More buoyancy.** Whales can grow larger and heavier than land animals because the water helps them support their weight. (*I don't know how creative you want to get here, but polar bear fur is hollow so maybe your C-rex does the same thing but produces helium to fill the fur to provide some buoyancy? Really stretching here.*) Or you could change your atmosphere.

Please see also: [Giraffatitan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giraffatitan) at 70-74ft in height and 30-60 tonnes in weight.

Source:
https://youtu.be/DkzQxw16G9w (3:00 mark)